# Not able to restore ".sql" file to pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4 and am trying to restore a .sql file which is a plain backup of the database created with pgAdmin 4. While trying to restore to the relevant database, it gives the following error:

[image: error_image]

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice "*Please use psql*" in the error message?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve it by using the command:

```
psql -U username -d database_name -f objects.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore a text format dump with pgAdmin. You have to use `psql` for it.

Use a custom format dump if you want to restore with pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

## This solution only works for **Windows**.

If you want to restore a database in pgadmin but the "restore" option in the UI is *not working at all*, try using the psql shell instead. First, ensure you have already added the postgres bin folder to the "Path" environment variable (in my case this folder is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin).

Then, open the Windows command interpreter (cmd), go to the folder where you have the .sql file and execute this command:

```
pg_restore -U userName -d database-1 backupfile.sql
```

For example:

```
pg_restore -U sam -d SamDataBase -1 SamDataBaseBackup.sql
```

(It can ask you for the password of the user so ensure to type it correctly and then click enter)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution only works for Windows.**

If you want to restore a database in pgadmin but the "restore" option in the UI is not working at all, try using the psql shell instead. First, ensure you have already added the postgres bin folder to the "Path" environment variable (in my case this folder is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin).

Then, open the Windows command interpreter (cmd), go to the folder where you have the .sql file and execute this command:

```
psql -U postgres dbname < file_restore.sql
```